# OpenSuse root commands error

Tags: linux, command-line, opensuse

Can someone explain why these commands doesn't work

```
me@suse:~> ifconfig
Absolute path to 'ifconfig' is '/sbin/ifconfig', so running it may require superuser privileges (eg. root).
```

.

```
me@suse:~> sudo ifconfig
root's password:
sudo: ifconfig: command not found
```

And why these work

```
me@suse:~> sudo /sbin/ifconfig
```

.

```
suse:/home/me # ifconfig
```

I know is something related with root user, but I want a better explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually user's with UID 0 (i.e. root) have a modified `$PATH` set, that includes directories like `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin`, while 'normal' user's don't have (since many programs in those directories require super-user privileges and won't be much usable for those normal users anyways).  Thus if a normal user wants to call anything in those directories missing in his `$PATH`, she has to specify the full path of the program, whilst 'root' can call them without this need.

Calling `sudo <program>` doesn't work either, because `sudo` does inherit its environment (and thus `$PATH`) from the calling process (which is unprivileged and thus missing `/sbin`).

You might try this out by calling `echo $PATH` one in your user's shell and once in a root-shell (not with `sudo`).

Comment: I've just added /usr/sbin to PATH and now it's working. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: i wonder: how does suse know the absolute path of a file which is not in $PATH?